# Difficuly in joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables , we are currently in normalizing stage and feeling difficulty . Could you please help me / give an idea on how to do that.

Below are the sample tables.

Table a ( Main table)

```
emp_id    Note1     note 2    note3
1         absdew   dgsjhdj   dsjshfjh
```

Table b

```
note_id  M_id  note
```

Table c

```
emp_id  note_id
```

Table D

```
 M_id        Name
joeshra   john shram
```

So now my question is , data from Table a, table d needs to be joined and migrate into table B and Table c

After inserting the two tables should look like,
**Table B :** (note_id is autogenerated)

```
(1,joeshra,absdew)   
(2,joeshra,dgsjhdj)
(3,joeshra,dsjshfjh)
```

**Table c** :

```
 (1, 1)
 (1, 2)
 (1, 3)
```

Comment: So you want to `UNPIVOT` your table A?

Comment: @Simon C ..yes..Could you help me as per  the result tables

Comment: The tags are wrong. Mysql or sql server ? mysql-workbench is just an IDE for mysql.

Comment: table a has only those 4 columns or Note.1 to Note.n?

Comment: there are total 5 notes..note1, 2,3,4,5

Comment: what does `M_id` refer to ?

Comment: M_id refers to msid ,which will be unique for each employee